# Exception starting filter MPIJSP Filter

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to set up a local tomcat (Apache Tomcat/7.0.47) server from eclipse.
I get my project from svn.
I set up the server and add the project into it.
Now I keep getting:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter MPIJSPFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: moreservlets.filters.MPIJSPFilter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and can not run the project or even when I run: localhost:8080/
I get: HTTP Status 404 - /

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Is that `MPIJSPFilter` part of your project code?

Comment: Yes I have a class MPIJSPFilter

Comment: Could I be missing: package moreservlets.filters; ?

Comment: This is the start of MPIJSPFilter.java                         package moreservlets.filters;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.mycheck.paymentmanager.utils.Logger;

import java.util.*; // For Date class
/** Simple filter that prints a report on the standard output
 * each time an associated servlet or JSP page is accessed.
 */

public class MPIJSPFilter implements Filter {

Comment: Try stopping the tomcat server,remove your project, restart tomcat, clean it, stop it, add back your project and restart.

Comment: @kharyam ,I did that. I did that several times. Apparently, Eclipse does not recognize the new files I added and changes I made...